# How to pass PHP variable value to Bakery Page Builder HTML Element - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wpbakery

I need to pass a variable (string or number) to an HTML element generated with WP Bakery Page Builder. I tried with shortcode, but I can't pass a variable but online an "hard coded" string.

I tried this:

```
global $my_var;
$my_var = "1234";
function wpc_vc_shortcode($my_var) {
return $my_var; // (I tried also with: echo $my_var;)
}
add_shortcode( 'my_vc_php_output', 'wpc_vc_shortcode');
```

Comment: We're going to need more information. What are you trying to accomplish by passing that variable? Where are you getting the variable from? Shortcodes get any passed arguments through an array - that the user would input. To use a variable in your code, you wouldn't pass it in, but you'd call the `global $my_var` **inside** the function - not pass it. The shortcode function doesn't know where `$my_var` is coming from.

Comment: $my_var value comes from a DB with a query. I want to pass the variable to write some text, for example: The phone number is $my_var

Comment: Are you adding the shortcode to the WP Bakery Element?

Comment: Yes to a text element